# Android WhisperSystems/libsignal-service

Tags: android

I am using WhisperSystems/libsignal-service library in android but I am getting one issue, I am not able to add library in my project. It is not taking lib version code, and on the WhisperSystems site also the not mentioned this things.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were trying to get here.

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/whispersystems/signal-service-android/2.3.0
```

You therefore need this section in your Gradle file.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
    jcenter()
```

You can see the full example here
 https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/blob/master/build.gradle

---

Latest version appears to be `2.5.4`, by the way

Comment: I tried with maven repositories and version code  2.5.4, but same error I am getting.....Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: org.whispersystems:libsignal-service-android:2.5.4